# Instagram user likes endpoint only returning public photos

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

The Instagram [endpoint to get the list of recent media liked by the owner of the access_token](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed_liked) only returns the **public** media liked by the owner. So if the owner liked a photo of someone they follow who has a private account, the API will not share this detail. Is there a scope issue or option I'm missing? Or is this simply an undocumented detail of the Instagram API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues , Instagram API works like that, when some account is private it doesn't fetch media that belongs to private account.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there not a way of getting this data with new scopes, (the likes scope)?

Comment: Unfortunately no.